# C++ using two incompatible libraries together, what are the options?

Tags: c++, dependencies, libraries, point-cloud-library, cgal

I wrote a program using the point cloud library (PCL). Now I want to use some of cgal's algorithms. I've managed to build a cgal class in isolation (all dependencies working etc.) but when I try and combine the two projects I get unresolved external symbol errors

So, what are my options for building a cgal project and accessing it (somehow) from my PCL project? I'd be passing a simple vector to the cgal project so in theory none of the specialist libraries have to interact with each other at all. 
I've tried building it into a static and dynamic library but as far as I know I still need to include all of the cgal dependencies when I do so -- this breaks things again.

**More info with regards to unresolved externals:**

I made a simple project (VS2010) using this [CGAL example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/Surface_reconstruction_points_3_2poisson_reconstruction_example_8cpp-example.html) adding required dependencies using CMAKE: CGAL components (including QT), TAUCS, LAPACK, BLAS. The project builds happily. If I add references to the PCL library:

```
include_directories (${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories    (${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
add_definitions     (${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

Now when I try to build I get four unresolved externals:

```
poisson.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void * __cdecl boost::detail::get_tss_data(void const *)" (__imp_?get_tss_data@detail@boost@@YAPAXPBX@Z) referenced in function "public: class CGAL::Lazy<class CGAL::Point_3<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> > >,class CGAL::Point_3<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Gmpq> >,class CGAL::Gmpq,class CGAL::Cartesian_converter<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Gmpq>,struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> >,struct CGAL::NT_converter<class CGAL::Gmpq,class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> > > > * __thiscall boost::thread_specific_ptr<class CGAL::Lazy<class CGAL::Point_3<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> > >,class CGAL::Point_3<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Gmpq> >,class CGAL::Gmpq,class CGAL::Cartesian_converter<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Gmpq>,struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> >,struct CGAL::NT_converter<class CGAL::Gmpq,class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> > > > >::get(void)const " (?get@?$thread_specific_ptr@V?$Lazy@V?$Point_3@U?$Simple_cartesian@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@CGAL@@@CGAL@@@CGAL@@V?$Point_3@U?$Simple_cartesian@VGmpq@CGAL@@@CGAL@@@2@VGmpq@2@V?$Cartesian_converter@U?$Simple_cartesian@VGmpq@CGAL@@@CGAL@@U?$Simple_cartesian@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@CGAL@@@2@U?$NT_converter@VGmpq@CGAL@@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@2@@2@@2@@CGAL@@@boost@@QBEPAV?$Lazy@V?$Point_3@U?$Simple_cartesian@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@CGAL@@@CGAL@@@CGAL@@V?$Point_3@U?$Simple_cartesian@VGmpq@CGAL@@@CGAL@@@2@VGmpq@2@V?$Cartesian_converter@U?$Simple_cartesian@VGmpq@CGAL@@@CGAL@@U?$Simple_cartesian@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@CGAL@@@2@U?$NT_converter@VGmpq@CGAL@@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@2@@2@@2@@CGAL@@XZ)
poisson.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl boost::detail::set_tss_data(void const *,class boost::shared_ptr<struct boost::detail::tss_cleanup_function>,void *,bool)" (__imp_?set_tss_data@detail@boost@@YAXPBXV?$shared_ptr@Utss_cleanup_function@detail@boost@@@2@PAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall boost::thread_specific_ptr<class CGAL::Lazy<class CGAL::Point_3<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> > >,class CGAL::Point_3<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Gmpq> >,class CGAL::Gmpq,class CGAL::Cartesian_converter<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Gmpq>,struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> >,struct CGAL::NT_converter<class CGAL::Gmpq,class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> > > > >::reset(class CGAL::Lazy<class CGAL::Point_3<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> > >,class CGAL::Point_3<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Gmpq> >,class CGAL::Gmpq,class CGAL::Cartesian_converter<struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Gmpq>,struct CGAL::Simple_cartesian<class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> >,struct CGAL::NT_converter<class CGAL::Gmpq,class CGAL::Interval_nt<0> > > > *)" (?reset@?$thread_specific_ptr@V?$Lazy@V?$Point_3@U?$Simple_cartesian@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@CGAL@@@CGAL@@@CGAL@@V?$Point_3@U?$Simple_cartesian@VGmpq@CGAL@@@CGAL@@@2@VGmpq@2@V?$Cartesian_converter@U?$Simple_cartesian@VGmpq@CGAL@@@CGAL@@U?$Simple_cartesian@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@CGAL@@@2@U?$NT_converter@VGmpq@CGAL@@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@2@@2@@2@@CGAL@@@boost@@QAEXPAV?$Lazy@V?$Point_3@U?$Simple_cartesian@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@CGAL@@@CGAL@@@CGAL@@V?$Point_3@U?$Simple_cartesian@VGmpq@CGAL@@@CGAL@@@2@VGmpq@2@V?$Cartesian_converter@U?$Simple_cartesian@VGmpq@CGAL@@@CGAL@@U?$Simple_cartesian@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@CGAL@@@2@U?$NT_converter@VGmpq@CGAL@@V?$Interval_nt@$0A@@2@@2@@2@@CGAL@@@Z)
poisson.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (__imp_?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::thread_exception::thread_exception(int,char const *)" (??0thread_exception@boost@@QAE@HPBD@Z)
poisson.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (__imp_?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'posix_category''(void)" (??__Eposix_category@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
```

I've been able to figure out most of these problems in the past but these blew my mind, hence why I wondered whether I could create two projects which interact but don't have to share libraries which aren't compatible.

Comment: Unresolved external symbols must be resolved, but without more info about that it is very difficult to help you. If you upload the complete output of the build process to pastebin.com, someone might help you more.

Comment: Not enough information. If you don't show your error message, we can't make it disappear.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: For my next trick, I'll make this linker error disappear. Wanna know how I got these chars?

Comment: Thanks everybody, I've added more detail to the question, I hope it is a little more enlightening.

Comment: It looks as if the boost thread library was missing.

Comment: @Wiredchop could you add `add_definitions(-DBOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC -DCGAL_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC)` in your CMakeLists.txt and recompile? With those macro definitions, the compiler will display messages about the CGAL and Boost auto-linking, during the compilation. Please edit your question to add the result.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and comments. I've tried a number of different things including upgrading my boost version to 1.55 and referencing my CGAL code as a static library. I've finally managed to compile the code by rebuilding CGAL to use the static boost libraries (as PCL does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP solved his own problem in a [comment section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266866/c-using-two-incompatible-libraries-together-what-are-the-options#comment41351009_26266866).

> I've tried a number of different things including upgrading my boost
>   version to 1.55 and referencing my CGAL code as a static library. I've
>   finally managed to compile the code by rebuilding CGAL to use the
>   static boost libraries (as PCL does).